# io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: A response error is detected: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden error using WebDriverManager and FireFox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, webdriver-manager

I am running my Selenium automation code in Firefox and getting the below error : 
**`io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: A response error is detected: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`**

It is working fine in Chrome browser.

FireFox version : 70.0.1 (64-bit)

OS : Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: A response error is detected: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

...was observed with someof the binaries (for Opera and Firefox) which are hosted on GitHub.

---

As per the discussion in [WebDriverManagerException: A response error is detected: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/263) [Boni García](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877746/boni-garc%c3%ada) referred this issue as a known issue within [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager).

In the [Known issues](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/doc/asciidoc/index.adoc#http-response-code-403) section it is documented that:

Some of the binaries (for Opera and Firefox) are hosted on GitHub. When several consecutive requests are made by WebDriverManager, GitHub servers return an HTTP 403 error response as follows:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.github.com/repos/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager.openGitHubConnection(BrowserManager.java:463)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.OperaDriverManager.getDrivers(OperaDriverManager.java:55)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager.manage(BrowserManager.java:168)
```

and some time as:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.FirefoxDriverManager.getDrivers(FirefoxDriverManager.java:61)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.BrowserManager.manage(BrowserManager.java:163)
```

---

This problem can be addressed by sending authenticated requests. The procedure is the following:

1. Create a token/secret pair in your GitHub account.
2. Tell WebDriverManager the value of this pair token/secret. To do that you should use the configuration keys `wdm.gitHubTokenName` and `wdm.gitHubTokenSecret`. You can pass them as command line Java parameters as follows:

   ```
    -Dwdm.gitHubTokenName=<your-token-name>
    -Dwdm.gitHubTokenSecret=<your-token-secret>
   ```

... or as environment variables (e.g. in Travis CI) as follows:

```
    WDM_GITHUBTOKENNAME=<your-token-name>
    WDM_GITHUBTOKENSECRET=<your-token-secret>
```